# Get value from muti dimensional-array textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of textbox which is dynamically generated and and named with multi-dimensional array for posting to php later.

```
<input type="text" name="node['A11']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['A11']['out']">
<input type="text" name="node['X22']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['X22']['out']">
<input type="text" name="node['C66']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['C66']['out']">
```

However, before the values get posted, i am trying to get the value of the specific textbox and do the validation.

```
var nodeValue = document.getElementsByName("node['X22']['in']").value;
alert(nodeValue);
```

Tried the above but it is not working. May i know is there a good way to parse trough the textbox list and get the specific textbox's value, let's say for 'X22' -> 'in'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns not a single element, but array-like object. Access the `[0]` indexed element of the result.

If you have unique elements, it will be better to get them by id (`getElementById`) which returns a single element.

```js
var nodeValue = document.getElementsByName("node['X22']['in']")[0].value
//                                                         ----^^^----
alert(nodeValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="node['A11']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['A11']['out']">
<input type="text" name="node['X22']['in']" value='SomeValue'>
<input type="text" name="node['X22']['out']">
<input type="text" name="node['C66']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['C66']['out']">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a value to get one

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="node['A11']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['A11']['out']">
<input type="text" name="node['X22']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['X22']['out']">
<input type="text" name="node['C66']['in']">
<input type="text" name="node['C66']['out']">
</body>

<script>

parse = function(){

var nodeValue = document.getElementsByName("node['X22']['in']");
console.log(nodeValue[0]);//to demonstrate that a nodelist is indeed returned.

}

parse()

</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `id` attribute and give it an identifier.

```js
var nodeValue = document.getElementById("X22in").value;
console.log(nodeValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="X22in" name="node['X22']['in']" value="foo">
<!--               ^^^^^^^^^^                                   -->
```